# What's a noun that has a meaning of a verb 'erase'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

How to transform verb 'erase' into a noun with the same meaning?

Comment: Have you checked an online dictionary or thesaurus? Or are you asking what the noun form of "erase" is? Like "erasure"?

Comment: I've voted to close as this question doesn't make sense to me.  Nouns and verbs are different parts of speech. Part of the meaning of "erase" is that it is a verb.  So a noun can't have the same meaning.  You might have an noun meaning the effect, or the action, or the thing that erases, or the thing that is erased.... but it can't be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Oxford Dictionary:

```
erasure, noun
​1. the act of removing writing, drawing, recorded material or data
- the accidental erasure of important computer files
- His drawings are full of erasures and redrawn lines.

2. ​the act of removing or destroying all signs of something
- the erasure of the past
- the regime's erasures of history and culture

Source: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/erasure
```

Eraser is also a noun, but usually refers to the piece of rubber used to erase pencil writings/drawings.